# JLabels only appear after resize of window

Tags: java, jframe

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

    JPanel panel1;
    JMenuBar daysMenu;
    JMenu[] days;
    JMenu chestMenu, backMenu, legsMenu, armsMenu, shouldersMenu;
    JMenuItem[] chest, back, legs, arms, shoulders;
    JLabel[] abs1, abs2;

    public Gui() {
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // setSize(1000,1000);
        setTitle("Gym Workout Program");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        days = new JMenu[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
            days[i] = new JMenu();
        }
        days[0].setText("MONDAY");
        days[1].setText("TUESDAY");
        days[2].setText("WEDNESDAY");
        days[3].setText("THURSDAY");
        days[4].setText("FRIDAY");
        days[5].setText("SATURDAY");
        days[6].setText("SUNDAY");
        daysMenu = new JMenuBar();
        for (JMenu day : days) {
            daysMenu.add(day);
        }
        setJMenuBar(daysMenu);

        // bodyPartsMenu
        chestMenu = new JMenu("Chest(1X12,2X10,2X8)");
        chest = new JMenuItem[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < chest.length; i++) {
            chest[i] = new JMenuItem();
        }
        chest[0].setText("Bench Press");
        chest[1].setText("Incline Press w/ Dumbbells");
        chest[2].setText("Chest Flyes w/ Dumbbells 180˚");
        chest[3].setText("Pullover w/ Dumbbells");
        chest[4].setText("Dips(Reps till failure/3X10)");
        for (JMenuItem item : chest) {
            chestMenu.add(item);
        }
        days[0].add(chestMenu);

        backMenu = new JMenu("Back(1X12,2X10,2X8)");
        back = new JMenuItem[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < back.length; i++) {
            back[i] = new JMenuItem();
        }
        back[0].setText("Pullups 3X10 TRYHARD/ Κ.Λ. Front Pulldowns");
        back[1].setText("Bend Over Row with Bar");
        back[2].setText("Lat Pulldowns");
        back[3].setText("Rowing Machine");
        for (JMenuItem item : back) {
            backMenu.add(item);
        }
        days[1].add(backMenu);

        days[2].add("KENO");

        legsMenu = new JMenu("Legs (1X12,2X10,2X8)");
        legs = new JMenuItem[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
            legs[i] = new JMenuItem();
        }
        legs[0].setText("Body Squat/Smith Machine/ w/Dumbbells");
        legs[1].setText("Leg Extensions Machine");
        legs[2].setText("Leg Curls Machine");
        legs[3].setText("Leg Press/ Walking Lunges w/ Dumbbells");
        legs[4].setText("Calves Machine 4X15");
        for (JMenuItem item : legs) {
            legsMenu.add(item);
        }
        days[3].add(legsMenu);

        armsMenu = new JMenu("Arms (1X12,2X10,2X8)");
        arms = new JMenuItem[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < arms.length; i++) {
            arms[i] = new JMenuItem();
        }
        arms[0].setText("Dumbbell Curls w/ twist");
        arms[1].setText("Larry Scot");
        arms[2].setText("Dumbbell Hammer Curls");
        arms[3].setText("SkullCrushers w/ Bar/Dumbbells");
        arms[4].setText("Triceps Press Downs");
        arms[5].setText("Reverse Triceps Press Downs");
        int countSeperator = 0;
        for (JMenuItem item : arms) {
            countSeperator++;
            armsMenu.add(item);
            if (countSeperator == 3) {
                armsMenu.addSeparator();
            }
        }
        days[4].add(armsMenu);

        shouldersMenu = new JMenu("Shoulders(1X12,2X10,2X8)");
        shoulders = new JMenuItem[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < shoulders.length; i++) {
            shoulders[i] = new JMenuItem();
        }
        shoulders[0].setText("Military Press Smith Machine");
        shoulders[1].setText("Lateral Raises");
        shoulders[2].setText("Shoulder Press Machine");
        shoulders[3].setText("Traps");
        for (JMenuItem item : shoulders) {
            shouldersMenu.add(item);
        }
        days[5].add(shouldersMenu);

        days[6].add("KENO");

        abs1 = new JLabel[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < abs1.length; i++) {
            abs1[i] = new JLabel();
        }
        abs1[0].setText("Full and Elbow Plank(1min each)");
        abs1[1].setText("Both Sides Plank(35-50 sec)");
        abs1[2].setText("Knee Up-LsitHold High Bar(1min each)");
        abs1[3].setText("HollowBodyHold(2X1min) LowerBackDown");
        abs1[4].setText("Wheel(2X8reps)");

        abs2 = new JLabel[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < abs2.length; i++) {
            abs2[i] = new JLabel();
        }
        abs2[0].setText("Leg Raises(3X12)");
        abs2[1].setText("Knee Raises(3X12)");
        abs2[2].setText("Side and Obliques(3X12)");

        JLabel abs3 = new JLabel("Free Choice");

        JLabel abs = new JLabel("Abs(3/3+ Times/week)");
        add(abs, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JRadioButton b1 = new JRadioButton("Style 1");
        JRadioButton b2 = new JRadioButton("Style 2");
        JRadioButton b3 = new JRadioButton("Style 3");
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(b1);
        group.add(b2);
        group.add(b3);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        b1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    for (JLabel label : abs1) {
                        panel2.add(label);
                    }
                }
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                    for (JLabel label : abs1) {
                        panel2.remove(label);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        b2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    for (JLabel label : abs2) {
                        panel2.add(label);
                    }
                }
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                    for (JLabel label : abs2) {
                        panel2.remove(label);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        b3.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    panel2.add(abs3);
                }
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                    panel2.remove(abs3);
                }
            }
        });

        add(panel2, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 50, 50));
        panel1.add(b1);
        panel1.add(b2);
        panel1.add(b3);

        add(panel1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I am trying to display my "abs workout" programme using JLabels and JRadioButtons.

I have used pack before `setVisible` and `setVisible(true)` after adding all the components but still my items(abs1 or abs2 or abs3) won't be displayed unless I resize my window.

When I click on Style 1 for example nothing happens and then if I resize my window everything seems to work fine.
Any help?

Comment: Add `revalidate();` to each of your ItemListeners, to tell Swing you’ve altered the component tree.

Comment: @VGR thanks that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changed the components in a container, you need to call revalidate() to schedule a re-layout of the container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `revalidate()` method after adding and removing the labels from the panel. Your code should look something like this.

```
if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
    for(JLabel label: abs1){
        panel2.add(label);
        revalidate();
    }
}
if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
    for(JLabel label: abs1){
        panel2.remove(label);
        revalidate();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: The answer is similar to what has been mentioned in the comments, and a previous answer :/

Comment: revalidate should be called once, after the if statements, not inside the loop.  Calling it repeatedly will not help, and may slow things down.

Comment: Righto! My bad.